# Excel Merge multiple cell content if cell = "fail"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am building an Excel formula to merge cells when a cell fails. The problem is, if there are multiple fails, I want the content of multiple cells to merge together for each fail.

```
=IF(H7="fail",CONCATENATE(E7),("No Text")=IF(H8="fail",CONCATENATE(E8),("No Text")))
```

I want the content from E7 and E8 in one cell if H7 and H8 are fails.

I want the content from E7 and E8 and E9 in one cell if H7 and H8 and H9 are fail.

I want the content from E7 and E8 in one cell if H7 is fail and H9 is fail and H9 is pass.

Right now, it only merges the content into one cell if you manually add it in.

```
=IF(H7="fail",CONCATENATE(E7,E8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=TRIM(IF(H7="Fail",E7,"") & IF(H8="Fail",E8,"") & IF(H9="Fail",E9,""))
```

Comment: @Kuchen22 Did this answer your question?  If so please mark as correct.  If not, pleas let me know where it failed so I can help fix the answer.